# php if stamens causing page to appear blank

Tags: php

I am using php to create a contact form that allows people to send me a message which is then sent to my email.

I had noticed that I was receiving a lot of spam messages. I deiced that I would add a captcha to rejoice the spam.

I have been able to display the captcha however I would like it that if the the user enters the contact letters/numbers and no of the other form fields  have been entered then the form will display a message to tell the user the message has been sent.

Here is the code I have tried

```
if($_SESSION["CAPTCHA_CODE"] == $captchaUser && !$errorName && !$errorEmail && !$errorMessage) {
    if ( mail($to, $subject, $body, $from) ) {
         $result='<div id="success" class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    }
}
```

However when I run this code my page appears blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Either `echo/print` the content or put somewhere in the html, so you would be able to see it.

Comment: I have tried that but still blank

Comment: Add `else` for failure cases.

Comment: probably mail is not being sent and if (mail( ... evaluates to false

Comment: check the status of your booleans with 
```var_dump(array('$errorName' =>$errorName))
```

Comment: Check the status of both if statements independently.

Comment: It is unclear where `$captchaUser` `$errorName` `$errorEmail` `$errorMessage` come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to check the CAPTCHA first, else it's hard to tell what the issue is:

```
$error = true;

if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    $message = 'Try session_start()';
} else if(! isset($_SESSION['CAPTCHA_CODE']) ) {
     $message = 'CAPTCHA absent';
} else if ($_SESSION["CAPTCHA_CODE"] !== $captchaUser) {
    $message = 'CAPTCHA mismatch';
} else if ($_SESSION["CAPTCHA_CODE"] === $captchaUser) {
    if ( mail($to, $subject, $body, $from) ) {
         $message = 'Thank You! I will be in toucht';
         $error = false; 
    } else {
        $message = 'mail not sent';
    }
} else {
    $message = 'unknown error';
}

if ($error) {
   die('<div id="error" class="alert alert-error">message: '.$message.'</div>')
} else {
    die('<div id="success" class="alert alert-success">message: '.$message.'</div>');
}
```

Comment: the page still comes up blank

Comment: Do you `<php echo $result; ?>` somewhere? Or maybe it's another script? While these variable are known, it should at least output something.

Comment: How you enabled error reporting for PHP? I've removed most variables but `$captchaUser`.

Comment: completely forgot I could enable error reporting, it has been a while since i have used php